# Highcharts bar: height by xAxis

Tags: highcharts, height

Have bar chart with many many entries on xAxis. But they are too close to each other.
Example: http://jsfiddle.net/XUsCq/

```
    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Africa', 'America', 'Asia', 'Europe', 'Oceania', 'Oceania', 'Oceania', 'Oceania', 'Oceania', 'Oceania', 'Oceania', 'Oceania', 'Oceania', 'Oceania', 'Oceania', 'Oceania', 'Oceania', 'Oceania', 'Oceania'],
        title: {
            text: null
        }
    },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Data is too dense.
change your container div in something like that:

```
<div id="container" style="min-width: 400px; margin: 0 auto; height: 800px"></div>
```

You can change the style for the dataLabels as:

```
plotOptions: {
                bar: {
                    dataLabels: {
                        enabled: true,
                        style: {
                             fontSize: "8px"
                         }
                    }
                }
            }
```

But that wont solution the problem if you have a lot of data anayway.

The best option would be resize the container according to the number of elements you are showing.

Here is a Fiddle link to inspire you:

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uCJx8/2/)

Comment: Chart is dynamic. And possible that there will be 2 entrie only.
http://jsfiddle.net/XUsCq/1/

Comment: on this case you shoud change the height by script, depending on the quantity of data that you have.

if you want a to play with the text size you can use: see my updated post.

Comment: Yes, my last mind was about same, count data and change height by script.

Comment: It think is the only way and use the function chart.setSize() instead resizing the container itself.

Comment: I modified the post with a link to Fiddle to inspire you.

Answer (score 0):

Your basic problem is that you have too much data to fit in the available space.

There are some highcharts options which can help: groupPadding and pointPadding in the plotOptions

```
 groupPadding:0,
 pointPadding:0,
```

Howver, the best thing you can do is make the chart a bit taller by setting a larger height on the containing div:

http://jsfiddle.net/eEHFH/